# When I Tried to change "Servlet-Class" name it throws http status 500

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web.xml, http-status-code-500

[image: see My project screenshot here] , [image: inside my class file is here]

I am a beginner to java ,jsp .I Don't know about the use of servlet and servlet-mapping. I think it is the connection between java and jsp.

What problem I encountered is when I tried changed the servlet-class and class name to Registers(which i underlined in red line) and run the program it throws this error-
HTTP Status 500 - Wrapper cannot find servlet class Registers or a class it depends on

I downloaded this project from internet.

If I Change the class name and servlet-class name back to old name as 'Register' it works perfectly

why I am getting this error.what should i do to change the class name.
Thank u.

Comment: did you change the class name in side the file Registers.java to Registers? The file name and class name have to be the same.

Comment: yeah Shiping,I did right click  the file and Refactor->rename.So it should have reflected inside the file too.

Comment: then did you rebuilt the class file? the IDE may not automatically rebuild the class file depending on your settings. and also make sure the rebuilt class files are actually deployed.